# Bash double quotes getting single quoted

Tags: bash

I have a problem, where my script argument, goes from this:

```
'_rofiarg: -mesg "State: Active:Enabled"'
```

To this (I strip the `_rofiarg:` using `cut` btw):

```
-mesg '"State:' 'Active:Enabled"'
```

As you can see, my purposeful double quotes get ignored, and Bash splits them into two words.

I'll rewrite a pseudocode here, as the original script has a lot of local dependencies to my configs.

```
#script1.sh
# $active and $state have some value, of course
script2.sh \
"_rofiarg: -mesg \"State: $active:$state\"" \
${somearray[@]};

#script2.sh
#Check input for rofi arguments, add them to Args(), all else goes to Data()
for Arg in "$@"; do
  if [[ "$Arg" =~ _rofiarg:* ]]; then
    Args+=( "$(echo "$Arg" | cut -c 11-)" );
  else
    Data+=( "$Arg" );
  fi;
done;
```

After this I just pass the `${Args[@]}` to the target program, in this case Rofi - like this:

```
out="$(
  printf '%s\n' "${Data[@]}" | 
    rofi -config $CONF/rofi/config.cfg \
      -dmenu    -no-custom  \
      -padding  $padd \
      ${Args[@]};
)";
```

I've been at this problem for hours. All of my statements about what actually gets passed to which program is logged using `set -o xtrace`, and I'm at a point, where I think I literally tried all random combinations of single, double, `$''`, and all other quote types.

Comment: Double quote that last use: `"${Args[@]}"`

Comment: @bishop Unfortunately, that yields the exact same result.

Comment: [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is relevant.

Comment: Probably not the best way, but this should work: `eval "Args+=($(echo "$Arg" | cut -c 11-))"`.

Comment: Why are you passing that string to your script in the first place, instead of parsing into a pair of correct arguments?

Comment: @chepner Good point actually, I guess I put on my tunnel vision glasses by accident. I'm gonna try that.

Comment: @chepner Changing my reaction to, that is unreasonably complicated. Having a delimitor, like '_rofiarg' and then a variable of either 1 or 2 arguments (Not all arguments are pairs, ex. `rm -f`) and deciding whether the argument is a pair is impossible.

Comment: The shell parses quotes and escapes before expanding variable values; thus if you put quotes and escapes in variables' values, they're treated as just part of the string, not as syntactic quotes around the string. You need to find a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
      ${Args[@]};
```

with the unquoted variable expansion is the point where the coherence between `"State:` and `…"` is lost. To prevent that, we have to quote the expansion, but in order to remove the quotes and to separate `-mesg` from `"State: …"`, we have to `eval`uate the command; this gives:

```
out="$(
  printf '%s\n' "${Data[@]}" | 
    eval rofi -config $CONF/rofi/config.cfg \
      -dmenu -no-custom \
      -padding $padd \
      "${Args[@]}"
)"
```